# OpenGL shader not passing variable from vertex to fragment shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I'm encountering something really really strange.

I have a very simple program that renders a simple full-screen billboard using the following shader pipeline:

**VERTEX SHADER:**

```
#version 430

layout(location = 0) in vec2 pos;

out vec2 tex;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(pos, 0, 1);
    tex = (pos + 1) / 2;
}
```

**FRAGMENT SHADER:**

```
#version 430

in vec2 tex;

out vec3 frag_color;

void main()
{
    frag_color = vec3(tex.x, tex.y, 1);
}
```

The program always renders the quad in the correct positions (so I've ruled out the VAO as culprit), but for some reason ignores whatever values I set for tex and always set it to vec2(0,0), rendering a blue box.

Is there something I'm missing here? I've done many opengl apps before, and I've never encountered this. :/

Comment: Are the elements of pos + 1 always less than 2?

Comment: yes. the box is bounded from (-1,-1) to (1,1). I can also do a direct assignment (eg: tex = vec2(0.5,0.5); ) and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I was thinking it was doing integer division, but if direct assignment still gives you the same issue, perhaps not.

Comment: Using a uniform, I can set color in the fragment shader. Uniforms don't work in the vertex shader (just like direct assignment)...

Comment: Do you have alpha channel enabled? If so, you should output `vec4` from fragment shader. Check your formats. Also, there should be `layout(location = 0)` for `frag_color`, but that shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: yeah, neither of those change anything. alpha is disabled (super simple C program). also, anything i set in the fragment shader is registered. anything i set in the vertex shader is essentially ignored.

Comment: something must be horribly wrong here... I'm rewriting parts of the program to see what the problem is. Thank you everyone for your input :)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen implementations of OpenGL 2.0 having problems at compile time when adding floats and not explicitly casted integers.
Even if it is not a problem I would think possible on a 4.3 implementation, maybe you should just add dots and suffixes to your "integer" constants.

The last line of you're vertex shader seems to be the only one that could be a problem (I believe values are always casted in constructors :p ) so you would have something like this instead:

```
tex = (pos + 1.0f) / 2.0f;
```

Remember that you're shaders can compile on **thousands of different implementations** so it's a good habit to **always be explicit!!!**

Comment: Note that `1.0` is of type `float` in GLSL, unlike in C/C++, where it is `double`. So the `f` suffix is not needed, and actually not supported in some OpenGL versions, like OpenGL 2.0 and ES 2.0.